# Get Multiple Lookup field for a ListItem in Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a lookup column that allows multiple values per item. I use the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK to retrieve all the column values for a list item:

```
ListItem item = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Items[itemId].ListItem.Fields.Request().GetAsync();
```

I also tried to retrieve the lookup column specifically:

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
   new QueryOption("expand", "fields(select=MultipleLookupColumn)"))
};
ListItem item = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Drive.Items[itemId].ListItem.Request(queryOptions).GetAsync();
```

It correctly shows the column values, including custom columns, except for the multiple lookup column.  The lookup column shows up in `item.Fields.AdditionalData`, but it is always an empty array, even when there are values assigned to it on Sharepoint Online.   But if I change the lookup column to disallow multiple values, it shows the value correctly.

How can I get the values of a multiple lookup column using the Graph API? Or are multiple lookup values not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is a permissions issue. I had it set up with the `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission, which is sufficient for reading the document library and files in Sharepoint Online, including lookup columns with single values. But unfortunately not lookup columns with multiple values. Once I added the `Sites.Read.All` permission, the multiple lookup values array was no longer empty.